# How do I force AWS Code Deploy to keep state between hooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

This is my first time using AWS's Code Deploy, so I'm probably/hopefully missing something obvious.

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby On Rails application to EC2 via Code Deploy.

Originally I wanted two `AfterInstall` stages, one to install things the system needs (RVM, Ruby, Postgres) and one to install gems. However, the second `AfterInstall` wouldn't see `rvm` or `bundle`. To save time I figured I would worry about splitting this out later and `bundle install` in the same hook, which works.

My issue is then with `ApplicationStart`, which can't see `bundle` - making `bundle exec puma...` impossible. I thought it was maybe because `rvm` wasn't kicking in to see which version of Ruby to use, so I added a `rvm use ruby-3.1.0` but it fails to see `rvm`.

Can someone explain what I'm missing that would allow individual hooks to build off of what has come before?

My `appspec.yml` looks like this;

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files: #copy files
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/timesheets/deployment
permissions: # def need deployment dir set to ec2-user, maybe not rvm?
  - object: /var/www/timesheets/deployment
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
  - object: /usr/local/rvm
    owner: ec2-user
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: deploy/arrange_folders
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: deploy/install
      timeout: 900
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deploy/start
```

The `BeforeInstall` hook moves some folders about to back-up the previous deployment.

My `install` script;

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e #exit on error

sudo yum install postgresql-devel
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql13

mkdir -p /var/www/timesheets
cd /var/www/timesheets

curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -

curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

rvm install ruby-3.1.0

gem install bundler

cd /var/www/timesheets/deployment

bundle install
```

My `start` script;

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e #exit on error

cd /var/www/timesheets/deployment

source /home/ec2-user/.env # tmp way to grab some ENVs

# rvm use ruby-3.1.0 # commented out because it also breaks

bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Error message

> [stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/515737d9-378b-4ecc-b2a9-080af25cb74a/d-XKE49L7SL/deployment-archive/deploy/start: line 6: bundle: command not found

### Notes

This is very much a spike, I'm aware that e.g. there is a better way to grab the gpg2 keys for rvm, I need a open another port which I will get around to! Having said that, all comments welcome!

Answer (score 1):

State is likely not the problem here as even within the same script (`install`), the command (`bundle`) that you've installed immediately before (`gem install`) cannot be found.

A few things to check/consider here:

- Consider moving the install script. Dependencies such as package managers, frameworks, etc. are typically placed into the `BeforeInstall` hook. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server) for more information.
- Check the full CodeDeploy log on the EC2 instance to see if there any other issues mentioned. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html) for more information.
- Run the same script on a fresh EC2 instance using the same image as your target instance to verify if it is executed successfully.
- If the script runs through successfully, validate the deployment package on the target instance. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-local.html) for more information.

Hope that helps to identify the root cause!